# UE4 How to run a game in unlit mode

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am wondering how can I play the game in Unlit mode or other modes (not in the Editing mode by changing the viewport).

Unlit mode can be better in some cases when you want to present the information without being affected by lighting conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this, when I press 0 then the game runs in Unlit mode

"Execute Console Command"

and then set the command as "viewmode unlit" without the quotes for of them

[image]